# nginx allow client_max_body_size for pattern

Tags: nginx

Im trying to acheive something like:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://nest:3500;
    include nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;

    if ($request_uri ~* ^/api/(a|b|e) ) {
        client_max_body_size 50m;
    }
}
```

but Im getting the error:

```
"client_max_body_size" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/cloud.conf:59
```

How is that possible within the `location /api/`  to allow  client_max_body_size for specific routes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is that possible within the location /api/  to allow client_max_body_size for specific routes?

## Use 2 location blocks

Other changes may be required, but just use 2 location blocks:

Either nested:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://nest:3500;
    include nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;

    location ~ ^/api/(a|b|e)/ {
        client_max_body_size 50m;
    }
}
```

Or not:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://nest:3500;
    include nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
}

location ~ ^/api/(a|b|e)/ {
    client_max_body_size 50m;

    proxy_pass http://nest:3500;
    include nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;

}
```

This allows greater control and avoid using `if` [which is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) and can easily cause a lot of confusion/problems.

Comment: Nice! Tjanks...